# Drupal watchdog database table flooded with same message over and over?

Tags: drupal, watchdog

I've:

- Disabled cron
- Disabled database logging
- Cleared my caches
- Commented out the code that is being displayed as the error

And still, the same error message is being written to Watchdog. I execute: "delete from watchdog" and IMMEDIATELY after I check in the watchdog table, the same error is there.

Not that it would help, but here's the error:

```
Details
Type    php
Date    Saturday, 31 October 2009 - 8:15pm
User    pieterlOHNO
Location    http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/node/104
Referrer    http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/import-contacts
Message Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/establis/public_html/modules/client_manager/client_manager.module on line 148.
Severity    error
Hostname    41.182.72.53
Operations
```

AND

```
Type    php
Date    Saturday, 31 October 2009 - 8:15pm
User    pieterlOHNO
Location    http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/node/104
Referrer    http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/import-contacts
Message fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/establis/public_html/modules/client_manager/client_manager.module on line 146.
Severity    error
Hostname    41.182.72.53
Operations
```

So, my questions are:

1. Is there any way to see why this specific error is being triggerred over and over?
2. What could be "caching" this error?
3. ANY other ideas on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to restart the server. MySQL was acting up.